# Android - share text to specified number

Tags: android, share, contacts, sharing

I am developing an Android application and I already have implemented a share function to share some text like this:

```
String shareBody = "some text";
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "BlaBlaBla");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send via"));
```

So when I call this functions I can choose between different sharing apps and contacts. Here is an example (taken from the web):

[image]

Now I want to implement another sharing function, but with a difference:

I also need to send/**share** a specific text **to a specific contact**, so when this function is called, I want it to show me different sharing options (I mean the various apps I can choose to share), but only for a specific telephone number, which I have in the app's database. For example I would see: "Sharing via:" and more options (each for every different sharing app) of the same person.

Is it clear? And Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Very useful feature but no support right now to show all the communication options available for sharing text for a specific contact. 
You have to show the options manually which has sending text for a contact. For example, show icons of SMS, gmail, etc which takes senders name/number and send text to the person using the service selected by the user.